# Enzyme mount does not render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Enzyme mount does not render a component. There are also other components with context but this is the only component I'm having troubles to test.

```
//LoginForm.js
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    //...
    render() {
        return (
            <AuthContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => (
                    <>
                        {!context.user && 
                            //stuff
                        }
                        {context.configurationCompleted && 
                        <>
                            //stuff
                        </>
                        }
                    </>
                )}
            </AuthContext.Consumer>);
    }
}
```

```
//LoginForm.test.js

describe('LoginForm', ()=>{
    let component;
    beforeAll(()=>{
        component = mount(
            <LoginForm/>, {context: {user: undefined, configurationCompleted: false}}
        );
    });
    test('works', ()=>{
        console.log(component.debug());
    });
});
```

Output is:
`<LoginForm />`

I just want to render the part below !context.user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive there were some issues with enzyme mount using options.context ( Check if you're using an up to date version). However, you can just use the classic COntext provider to inject the value:

```js
it("displays the result", () => {
    const component = mount(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ context: { user: undefined, configurationCompleted: false } }}>
            <LoginForm />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
```